# Unable to push to mercurial repository

Tags: maven, version-control, jenkins, mercurial, maven-release-plugin

We have setup a Release plan on our Jenkins server.
When the maven release plugin did his job a push is being made to our Mercurial server but we always get the following error:

```
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-release-plugin:2.5:prepare
(default-cli) on project myProject: Unable to commit files
[ERROR] Provider message:
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] EXECUTION FAILED
[ERROR] Execution of cmd : push failed with exit code: 255.
[ERROR] Working directory was:
[ERROR] /var/lib/jenkins/jobs/ReleaseBuildJob/workspace
[ERROR] Your Hg installation seems to be valid and complete.
[ERROR] Hg version: 1.4 (OK)
[ERROR]
```

I've already check several things:

The .hgrc file in the home directory of the jenkins user contains the following:

```
[ui]
username = jenkins <no-reply@my.jenkins.be>

[auth]
myProject.prefix = http://myserver/hg
myProject.username = myUsername
myProject.password = myPassword
```

Our POM file contains the following data:

```
 <scm>
    <connection>scm:hg:http://myserver/hg/myProject</connection>
    <developerConnection>scm:hg:http://myserver/hg/myProject</developerConnection>
  </scm>
```

The Jenkins server is able to pull from this Mercurial repository but it is not able to push.

What am I missing?

Comment: Is there any way to get the stdout/stderr from Mercurial itself?  Those logs don't appear to include that.

Comment: I don't have a clue where to find this. It would be useful however...

Comment: http://blog.whitehorses.nl/2014/03/17/using-the-maven-release-plugin-with-mercurial-scm/

Comment: I've also discovered I've the following issue when just trying to push to this server: abort: HTTP Error 414: Request-URI Too Large